# Checking if window.pageYoffset is >= to set value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change some css styling when the page is scrolled past a certain distance using pageyoffset. I'm very new to javascript so don't know how to correctly write it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
if ((window.pageYOffset) >= 240) {
    var hero = document.getElementById('hero')
    hero.style.position = "fixed"
    hero.style.top = "-140px"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the logic exactly right, you simply need to wrap your conditoinal inside a 
 `window.onscroll = function() { }`.

Note that in the following example, I've replaced your two style changes with one that simply adds a background, to showcase this working.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  if ((window.pageYOffset) >= 240) {
    var hero = document.getElementById('hero')
    //hero.style.position = "fixed";
    //hero.style.top = "-140px";
    hero.style.background = "green";
  };
}
```

```css
#one {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="hero">Hi</div>
```

Note that you should also `unbind` the scroll functionality once the desired behaviour has been completed, which can be done with jQuery's [**`.unbind()`**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method:

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

You could alternatively use `addEventListener()` and `removeEventListener()` if you want to stick with vanilla JavaScript.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Should unbind `window.onscroll` after the condition is hit so that it doesn't continuously fire.

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate the time works perfect.

Comment: I'm trying to stick to JS like you said as I'm soon to be studying it and don't want to confuse myself with JQuery. Thanks for the tip about removeEventListener I was wondering how to do that as when I was using an alert to test previously it was causing my browser to crash due to it continuously firing.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the idea if don't tell me

```js
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll > 800) {
    $('#hero').css('background-color','yellow');
}
else if(scroll<800){
$('#hero').css('background-color','red');
}
});
```

```css
div{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
#hero{
  height:1500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='hero' style='background-color:red'>

</div>
<div style='background-color:blue'>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'm sure that works but is it not JQuery? excuse me if I'm wrong I'm really new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an event to check for the scoll position like:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScrollPosition);
```

and then put your code above in a function to handle the event

```
function checkScrollPosition(){
   if ((window.pageYOffset) >= 240) {
   var hero = document.getElementById('hero')
   hero.style.position = "fixed"
   hero.style.top = "-140px"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has done the trick it's weird though because I tried this previous to commenting and couldn't get it to work. Must have made a typo somewhere.